# How to set defaultProps for function?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to set defaultProps for functions? Code below doesn't work. It doesn't like 'this'. I tried 1_ bind defaultProps to 'this', or 2_ bind handleClose to 'this', neither works. I use ES6 class.

```
SaveDialog.propTypes = {
  note: React.PropTypes.string,
  onCancel: React.PropTypes.func,
  onSave: React.PropTypes.func,
  onEditChange: React.PropTypes.func
};

SaveDialog.defaultProps = {
  note: '',
  onCancel: {this.handleClose},
  onSave: {this.handleClose},
  onEditChange: {this.handleChange}
};
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`propTypes` is a validator. We use propTypes to document the intended property types passed to components. React checks the props passed to components against those definitions, and will result in a warning/error when they don’t match.

We can define default values to props using the `defaultProps` property. defaultProps is used to ensure that props will have a value if it was not specified by the parent component. The propTypes type-checking happens after defaultProps are resolved, so type-checking will also apply to the defaultProps.

Here we have

```
SaveDialog.propTypes {
  note: PropTypes.string,
  onCancel: PropTypes.func,
  onSave: PropTypes.func,
  onEditChange: PropTypes.func,
};
```

React is making sure that the `note` prop is a string, and is making sure the `onSave`, `onCancel`, and `onEditChange` props are functions. If not, it will result in a warning/error.

Here we have

```
SaveDialog.defaultProps {
  note: '',
  onCancel: {this.handleClose},
  onSave: {this.handleClose},
  onEditChange: {this.handleChange},
};
```

In SaveDialog.propTypes, `note` has been declared as a string. Let’s assume that a prop has not been specified by the parent container. Since note has no value, we will use the default value provided in defaultProps. The default value of note is an empty string. When type-checking occurs, we see that the prop is intended to be a string and is, in fact, an empty string. No problems here, let’s move on.

Next up, `onCancel` in SaveDialog.PropTypes {...}; onCancel has been declared as a func (function). Assuming that a prop has not been specified by the parent container, we’ll use the default value of onCancel in defaultProps. The default value is `this.handleClose`.

Let’s talk about what’s going on here.
To put it simply, `this` is referring to the object that invoked the function.

In that case, `defaultProps` does not have access to the `onCancel` function, and because onCancel wasn’t defined within `defaultProps`, it returns `undefined`, or an error/warning.

If that's the case, all we have to do is define what we want `onCancel` to be within `defaultProps`.

So we can declare the functions within defaultProps or we can have the default value be an empty function making it clear that onCancel, onSave or the onEditChange functions are empty functions that return undefined.

```
SaveDialog.defaultProps {
  note: '',
  onCancel: () => {},
  onSave: () => {},
  onEditChange: () => {},
};
```

or

```
SaveDialog.defaultProps {
  note: '',
  onCancel: () => {
        // handleClose function here
  },
  onSave: () => {
    // handleClose function here
  },
  onEditChange: () => {
    // handleChange function here
  },
};
```

Comment: Don't just blurt out code. Adding some text to explain how this best answers the question will improve the long-term value of the answer and prevent it from being deleted during review.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the getDefaultProps method.

```
getDefaultProps() {
  return {
    note: '',
    onCancel: this.handleClose.this(bind),
    onSave: this.handleClose.this(bind),
    onEditChange: this.handleChange.this(bind)
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the default props for the component and attach the function to the component in the constructor.

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.extFunction = extFunction.bind(this);
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Either runtime error as 'undefined' or compile error syntax.