# PropTypes.defaultProps for a function in a stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

### Problem

I have a functional component that might receive an optional function as a prop. I am using propTypes to define the default values of the props that are not proportionated. Is there any way to define the default value of a function (in defaultProps) to an especific component's function?

### Code

```
export default function Cropper(props) {
   ...
   const handleOnCrop = () => { // <-------
      // Stuff
   }
   ...

   const handleConfirm = () => {
      if (!isCropping) {
          setIsCropping(true);
          cropPhoto().then((croppedPhoto) => {
            onCrop(croppedPhoto); // <----------------
            InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
              setIsCropping(false);
            });
          });
       }
    };
}
```

### PropTypes

```
Cropper.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  photo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onCrop: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

Cropper.defaultProps = {
  onCrop: // This has to be the functional component function "handleOnCrop" <--------
};
```

### Solution Approach

```
Cropper.defaultProps = {
  onCrop: (photo, navigation) => { // <---------- Passing the navigation object from the component is not really good
    navigation.navigate("PostCreator", {
      photo,
    });
  },
};
```

I think that this is not the best way to handle this but working for me. Anyways, I need to change it to something like in stateful components.

Comment: What you dou need to achieve with that function? Can you describe what should happen, if the fallback would be used?

Comment: In this function I use the navigation prop (from the component) to navigate to other screen. That is why I can't implement the function inside the defaultProps body.

Comment: You can attach default functions in `defaultProps`. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436162/how-to-set-defaultprops-for-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set defaultProps for function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436162/how-to-set-defaultprops-for-function)

Comment: I saw it before but not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this right, you need to express a type which is not one of PropType's available exports (object, func, arrayOf etc.). If that is the case, I see some solutions, these vary on how specific you need your PropTypes to be.

```
PropTypes.instanceOf
```

https://github.com/facebook/prop-types#usage

Take a look at the anchored section from the URL. In the example you can find the following snippet:

```
  // You can also declare that a prop is an instance of a class. This uses
  // JS's instanceof operator.
  optionalMessage: PropTypes.instanceOf(Message),
```

I think you could reuse this in your case if you have a valid export / import of

```
 the functional component function "handleOnCrop"
```

as you mentioned.

This is by far the most specific prop type I can think of right now. Let's look at some other solutions.

If you are alright with generalizing the prop a bit more, you can resort to

```
PropTypes.node
```

Which is described as following from the url mentioned above:

```
// Anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, elements or an array
  // (or fragment) containing these types.
  optionalNode: PropTypes.node,
```

My least favorite solution,

```
PropTypes.any
```

I think this is pretty self-explanatory, and not something you are looking for, so you should use this as last resort.

This is an answer based on my understanding of your question, feel free to leave a comment to explain it further.

Comment: The PropTypes is just a function. My problem is that I need this to be the function which is implemented inside the functional component. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Raul I took a look at your solution approach, and I do not see anything wrong with it, at least in my opinion. What you are doing in essence is providing the default prop to be an anonymous arrow function which takes in the props photo & navigation. What I would advise to do is add an if clause to check wether you actually did get navigation & photo props in that function.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a good practice, it is rare, but maybe the only way to do it in a functional component.